# Publishing rmdformats

Tags: r, r-markdown

Trying to publish a rmdformats::material package to the web

I created an r markdown using the package rmdformats::material but I can't figure out how to publish it to the web.

````
---
title: "rmdformats"
author: "Holly"
output:
  rmdformats::material:
    self_contained: no
    css: style.css
---


```{r knitr_init, echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(rmdformats)

```
````

Every time I embed it, the report does not render.  I have gotten normal R Markdowns to work, but when I use this package- no luck.

Comment: So you're knitting to an HTML file? Then what are you doing to publish that file? And embed it where?

Comment: In the past, we have been able to upload the HTML file as an attachment into Google Drive, then get a shareable link from there.  This is what I am attempting now.

Comment: Can you try with `self_contained: true`?

Comment: I just tried it and got this error:  File style.css not found in resource path
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 99
In addition: Warning message:
MathJax doesn't work with self_contained when not using the rmarkdown "default" template. 
Execution halted